# DotCover не видит покрытие тестами строчки c IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xunit

DotCover не видит покрытие тестами в строчке 212. Если добавить .ToList(), как указана на втором скрине, то покрытие тестов отображается. Количество тейс-кейсов и заполнения всех полей в тест-кейсе не решает эту проблему. Как можно решить эту проблему не добавляя .ToList()?
[image: Пример кода с не покрытой тестами строчкой кода тестами от DotCover]

[image: Пример кода с покрытой тестами от DotCover]

Comment: Коллекция не материализована, а значит ваш делегат не был вызван. Все правильно вам dotcover показывает.

Comment: Как решить проблему - вам надо в тесте пройтись по коллекции. Вы, видимо, в своём тесте содержимое коллекции не проверяете.

Comment: Другими словами отложенное выполнение LINQ. При ToList() операция выполняется сразу

Answer (score 0):

Коллекция не материализована, а значит ваш делегат не был вызван. Все правильно вам dotcover показывает. – [@tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1321894/dotcover-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%5D%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-c-ienumerable/1371043#comment2335423_1321894)

Как решить проблему - вам надо в тесте пройтись по коллекции. Вы, видимо, в своём тесте содержимое коллекции не проверяете. – [@tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1321894/dotcover-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-c-ienumerable/1371043#comment2335424_1321894)

Comment: это больше похоже на комментарий, адресованный tym32167, а не ответ.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, это ответ, сформированный из комментариев участника tym32167